# Textbox inside panel .NET 1.1 KeyUp

Tags: c#, .net, .net-1.1

Basically, I have a textbox inside a panel. In v1.1 framework shortcuts like ctrl + C and ctrl + V are not implicit for textboxes and have to be coded for the KeyUp event. So, I created a general class that inherits textbox and has an eventhandler for copy and paste via keyboard shortcuts.
The problem that I have is that when I ctrl + V inside a textbox that is in a panel it double copies the text. I was thinking that this may be because the panel(scrollable  control) has the KeyUp event already set for paste-ing and that one fires up first and then the one I wrote. I was thinking if there is anyway to override the the panel's KeyUp event so it does not trigger a paste? ( if my logic is correct) Any ideas are welcome as to why the double paste occurs. ( the double paste only occurs in a textbox that is inside a panel)

```
private void dbTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C)) (sender as TextBox).Copy(); 
 if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.V)) (sender as TextBox).Paste(); 
}
```

Comment: can you share a code snippet of whats happening inside the key up event?

Comment: ' private void dbTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
  {

          

   if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C))   (sender as TextBox).Copy();
   if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.V))  (sender as TextBox).Paste();
  
  } '

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `e.Handled = true;`